# Метафора или метонимия?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, тропы

В чем разница между метафорой и метонимией?

**Морской котик** - метафора? метонимия? Или это вообще "не из той оперы"?
А просторечное **"геморрой"** - в значении *морока, проблемы*?

*Исходно вопрос возник в связи с переводом английского fingerprints (в значении [неопропровержимые] улики, вещдоки) термином "отпечатки пальцев". Но это английский, да и историю не все знают. Но если кто прокомментирует и это, возражать не буду.*

Answer (score 1):

(Частичный ответ.)

Метафору в таких простых случаях можно отличить, переформулировав высказывание в виде сравнения, если при этом не теряется смысл этого высказывания. "Геморрой" (или, как говорят в Питере, "головняк" :) под этот критерий подходит нормально, а "морской котик" — очевидно, нет.

Comment: Метафора сама по себе - сравнение, а вот насчет "всегда можно переформулировать" - что-то я не уверен...Масло масляное получается. Как можно **сравнение** (метафору) переформулировать *в виде сравнения*? И в чем смысл такого действа? Что-то тут не ладно в школьной формулировке.

Comment: @Мимоходов Объяснение детское, зато в таких простых случаях оно вполне работает. Вы ведь сомневались в "морском котике"? Значит, подозревали здесь сравнение. Какое? Попытайтесь оформить его в явном виде. "Морской, словно котик"? Вряд ли. "Животное, похожее на котёнка, только живущее в море"? Не намного лучше. Дайте подходящее сравнение и я, возможно, сниму ответ.

Comment: Боже избави, не надо ничего снимать. В котике я не только сомневаюсь, но и уверен, что это не  метафора, но по другим причинам, которые были непонятны моим собеседникам. Я же сомневаюсь именно в универсальности критерия. И по-хорошему это не мне надо искать  сравнения для "котика", а вам для понимания привести таковое для "геморроя". Для иллюстрации универсальности критерия.

Comment: Я сам такое выражение не использую, но особых сложностей не вижу. Выражение "эта проблема — геморрой" (так его употребляют?); сравнение: "эта проблема доставляет мне такие же неудобства, как геморрой".

Comment: Я не буду настаивать на универсальности. Тема "метафоры" в языке не такая уж простая, конечно. Я откорректировал ответ.

Comment: *"эта проблема доставляет мне такие же неудобства, как геморрой"* Ууууу... Ну тогда держите: "Это животное такое же шелковистое,  как котик". Вы включили в сравнение скрытый характеристический признак, чем действительно превратили в метафору, но сам прием сомнителен.В метафоре этот признеак должен быть явным. Сравните: коньки (не морские) - от "конь". Или "медведь" - сорт крепких коктейлей.

Comment: Ладно, уже движок ругается... Придется завершить. Спасибо.

Comment: _Ну тогда держите_ Ну тогда у Вас тоже метафора. Просто её многие либо не поймут без пояснения, либо не сочтут удачной. Многое зависит от культурного контекста. Я думаю, что в самом общем виде это очень сложный вопрос. Я не смогу дать на него исчерпывающий ответ. В качестве частичного, считаю свой ответ удовлетворительным.