# "Глядим в Наполеоны" - грамматика или троп?

Tags: грамматика, тропы

В развитие вопроса [Метафора или метонимия?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440975)

В [википедическом словаре](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/20606) пушкинское "Мы все глядим в Наполеоны" названо синекдохой - якобы тут используется множественное число вместо единственного. Насколько это верно? Для меня это всего лишь так называемый "второй винительный падеж" наподобие "метить в министры" или "забрить в солдаты".

И почему тогда у Пушкина личное имя с заглавной? Тут ведь нарицательное значение, нет?

//----------

В связи с первым ответом уточню. Вопрос у меня именно в том, есть ли у Пушкина синекдоха, остальное - вольный экскурс. То есть действительно ли тут имеет место замена единственного на множественное. В примерах *"метить в министры"* и *"забрить в солдаты"* - никакой замены нет, там *по грамматике положено множественное*.

Comment: Наверно, надо подправить "МетАфора" и "викИпедическом" и, возможно, добавить метку "тропы".

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова ОК. Насчет метки я, правда, реально сомневаюсь, но пусть будет.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, здесь всё-таки синекдоха.

"Метить в министры" и "забрить в солдаты" - синекдохи нет, потому что для этих слов множественное число естественно: много министров, много солдат, а вот Наполеон - имя собственное, и не просто собственное, оно обозначает единственную историческую личность, есть много людей с именем Наполеон, но мы-то имеем в виду именно Наполеона Бонапарта, он один. Если б  сказали "мы все глядим в гении", было б в прямом значении, а здесь имеет место перенос по смежности, основанный на количественном признаке (говорим "в Наполеоны", а имеем в  виду  одного Наполеона),  как и обратное ему "но ликовал француз" - единственное вместо множественного.

Comment: Меня немного смущает невозможность избежать множественного числа в обороте "гладеть в..." Во всех остальных примерах синекдохи такого нет. Получается, так сказать, вынужденная синекдоха.

Comment: @Людмила "Баллотироваться в Президенты"? "Выбиться в лидеры"? Только не говорите, что их, Президентов и Лидеров больше одного, а то я вспомню, что Наполеонов тоже четыре было. А у Конана Дойла - и того больше. ("Шесть Наполеонов").

Comment: @Людмила "Актрису, игравшую бабушку, перевели в Красные Шапочки". )))) Троп? А если "разжалован из Наполеонов"? Ну и на вопрос М_Г тоже хочу ответ увидеть.

Comment: М_Г, , но ведь оттого, что она вынужденная, она не перестала быть синекдохой. Просто она сочетается с другими процессами языка. В ряде случаев имена собств. могут образовывать мн. ч. от формы ед. ч., но при этом происходит изменение лексич. значения, т.е. добавляются смысловые оттенки лексического типа, например, когда слово в мн.ч. используется для обобщения, для обозначения целого класса лиц.   Мы все глядим в Наполеоны - мы все желаем быть Наполеонами, войти в класс Наполеонов.  По Кузнецову, "глядеть  в" - мысленно представлять, желать. Г. в прошлое, Г. в будущее... глядим в Наполеоны

Comment: Так что смысла нет искать, что здесь главное - грамматическое явление использования мн.ч. для обобщения, переход имени собственного в нарицательное или стилистическое  использование синекдохи как метафорического явления. Оно всё здесь есть, можно им аргументировать все эти явления. Это и синекдоха, и изменение лексического значения с помощью изменения числа.

Comment: Появление переносного смысла - это ведь тоже явление метафоризации.

Answer (score 2):

**Синекдоха** — это соотнесение, употребление части вместо целого, частного вместо общего и наоборот. В частности сюда относят **замену ед. числа мн. числом для имен собственных.**

Наполеон полагал для себя возможным свободно распоряжаться чужими судьбами, и людей, которые разделяют это мнение, считают себя "право имеющими," называют Наполеонами. Качество человека ("наполеонизм") становится **нарицательным,** но людей, носителей этого качества, обозначают  **именем собственным в форме мн. числа.**

**У Розенталя**: Если фамилия, употребленная в нарицательном значении, **не переходит в разряд существительных нарицательных**, сохраняется написание с прописной буквы: Мы… твёрдо были уверены, что имеем своих Байронов, Шекспиров, Шиллеров, Вальтер Скоттов (Бел.).

Но если индивидуальное название человека употребляется в презрительном смысле, как родовое обозначение, то оно пишется со строчной буквы: презренные носке и шейдеманы (‘предатели социал-демократы’), квислинги (‘коллаборационисты’).

Примеры:

Слышу ваш топот чугунный По еще не открытым **Памирам** (В. Брюсов).

Плевать, что нет **у Гомеров и Овидиев** людей, как мы, от копоти в оспе (В. Маяковский).

Лгут обольстители-мистики, **никаких Карибских морей** нет на свете, и не плывут в них отчаянные флибустьеры, и не гонится за ними корвет, не стелется над волною пушечный дым. Нет ничего, и ничего и не было! (М. Булгаков)

Comment: Ну так почему у Пушкина-то не переходит в нарицательные? Впрочем, это это вообще не тот вопрос. Что с синекдохой? Вы согласны, что у Пушкина именно она?!

Comment: Да. согласна. По-моему, во всех примерах использован один и тот же принцип, в том числе у Пушкина. Но Вы, наверное, считаете, что у Пушкина речь идет об отрицательном качестве.  Я как раз задумалась  над тем, почему У Розенталя такое решение относительно "презрительного смысла".  Мне кажется, что прописные буквы, которые могут обозначать  смысл высокий , вступают в противоречие  с чувством презрения. Что касается Наполеона, то при всем неприятии его отношения к людям мы не можем отказать этому  историческому лицу в величии и презирать его.

Comment: *Но Вы, наверное, считаете, что у Пушкина речь идет об отрицательном качестве.* - совсем нет, я просто вижу здесь явно переносный смысл. Ваша трактовка мне понятна, но я её не очень разделяю. У Пушкина подчеркивается скорее всего не то качество Н., которое вы отметили, а всего лишь величие самой фигуры. То есть, на мой вкус, тут Пушкин говорит всего лишь о "чувстве собственного высокомерия". И Наполеон становится именем нарицательным. Но это лучше бы отложить до решения вопроса о синекдохе.

Comment: *По-моему, во всех примерах использован один и тот же принцип* - "взять в жены", "записаться в студенты" - тоже синекдоха? Но где тогда вообще граница между ней и вторым винительным падежом? Как построить фразу без синекдохи? Ведь её классическое понимание предполагает именно замену единственного на множественное (или наоборот). Но "взять в жену" - это что-то другое, совершенно непригодное к употреблению.

Comment: Нет, это не синекдоха. . Я посмотрела в Грамматике-80 значение В.падежа. Этот падеж, как и другие, является многозначным. В данном случае названо его частное значение - вхождение в класс предметов. Вступить в полк, пойти в армию. выйти в знать - это ед. число. Произвести в офицеры,  проситься в помощники, взять в свидетели - это мн. число, если  речь идет о вхождении в общественную группу, обозначенную одушевленными существительными.

Comment: Ну пусть будет многозначным, хотя логичнее выделить в отдельную падежную форму "включительный или второй винительный падеж". Суть не в этом... Где граница? Чем грамматически вхождение в класс Наполеонов отличается от включения в класс жён?

Comment: Наверное тем, что класс жен обозначен нарицательным существительным, а класс людей, подобных Наполеону, обозначен именем собственным.

Comment: Ну хорошо, а как тогда эта фраза будет выглядеть без синекдохи? Ведь если тут синекдоха, то это замена множественным числом единственного. Как сказать фразу без этой фигуры речи? В единственном числе?

Comment: Может быть так: Каждый из нас видит себя Наполеоном.

Comment: Но это же совсем другая фраза.))) С другой грамматикой, другим глаголом, другим управлением. ))) Ладно, спасибо, движок уже ругается.

Comment: Ну да, другая, но с похожим смыслом.  Вероятно, пушкинская фраза не поддается переделке. И Вам спасибо за приятное общение.

Comment: @Jasmin Мне именно Ваш ответ ближе и понятнее. Я с удовольствием его "заценила".

Comment: Спасибо. Но и вопрос был интересный.

Answer (score 0):

> “Глядим в Наполеоны” - грамматика или троп?

Я считаю, что это троп, а не грамматика. В данном случае мы имеем композицию метонимий: сначала использована антономазия (употребление собственного имени в значении нарицательного), затем — синекдоха.

Comment: Мысль понял. Но как вы трактуете примеры типа "вышел в люди", "записался в студенты" и проч.? Тоже синекдоха?

Comment: Я бы счёл подобного типа выражения фразеологизмами.

Comment: Ну что вы, форма-то продуктивная, членимая. Это включительный, он же второй винительный (не путать с историческим "двойным винительным") падеж. Споры идут о том, признавать ли за ним статус падежа, но само грамматическое явление никто не отрицает. http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6

Comment: Тогда я лучше не буду рисковать спорить или искать на ходу другое решение. Не уверен.